# Android Toolbar always on top and uncovering

Tags: android, toolbar

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        tools:parentTag="android.widget.RelativeLayout">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                    app:titleMargin="0dp"
                    app:titleMarginEnd="0dp"
                    app:titleMarginStart="0dp"
                    app:titleMargins="0dp"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/custom_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/left_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/left_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_white_pressed_gray"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/right_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_white_pressed_gray"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/right_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

1. I want to customize the layout, but the custom_title layout is always under the Toolbar.
2. I don't want to place custom_title inside the  label.
   How do I make the custom_title layout appear at the top of the Toolbar?
   Why the Toolbar always on top?
3. Because Toolbar is a ViewGroup and it set more padding and child view.if put the custom_title layout in  ,it will cause the custom_title to be unable to center.

public class ToolbarLayout extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private static final int DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE = 16;
private static final int DEFAULT_TITLE_SIZE = 18;
private static final int DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
private AppCompatActivity activity;
private LayoutToolbarBinding binding;
private OnClickListener listener;
private String leftText, title, rightText;
private int leftColor, leftSize, leftImage, leftTextLIcon, leftTextRIcon;
private int titleSize, titleColor, titleTextIcon;
private int rightSize, rightImage, rightColor, rightTextLIcon, rightTextRIcon;
private boolean showBackup, showElevation;
private int backgroundColor;

public void setListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public ToolbarLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.layout_toolbar, this, true);

    if (context instanceof AppCompatActivity) {
        activity = (AppCompatActivity) context;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This context is not a AppCompatActivity instance");
    }
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ToolbarLayout);
    showBackup = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_showBackup, true);
    showElevation = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_showElevation, false);
    leftText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_leftText);
    title = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_title);
    rightText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_rightText);
    leftColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_leftTextColor, DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR);
    titleColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_titleColor, DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR);
    rightColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_rightTextColor, DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR);
    leftSize = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_leftTextSize, DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
    titleSize = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_titleTextSize, DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
    rightSize = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_rightTextSize, DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
    leftTextLIcon = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_leftTextLIcon, 0);
    leftTextRIcon = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_leftTextRIcon, 0);
    titleTextIcon = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_titleTextIcon, 0);
    rightTextLIcon = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_rightTextLIcon, 0);
    rightTextRIcon = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_rightTextRIcon, 0);
    leftImage = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_leftImage, 0);
    rightImage = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_rightImage, 0);
    backgroundColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.ToolbarLayout_backgroundColor, ResourceHelper.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    typedArray.recycle();
    setDefault();
}

private void setDefault() {
    setLeftText(leftText);
    setLeftColor(leftColor);
    setLeftSize(leftSize);
    setLeftDrawable(leftTextLIcon, leftTextRIcon);
    setTitle(title);
    setTitleColor(titleColor);
    setTitleSize(titleSize);
    setTitleTextIcon(titleTextIcon);
    setRightText(rightText);
    setRightColor(rightColor);
    setRightSize(rightSize);
    setRightDrawable(rightTextLIcon, rightTextRIcon);

    setLeftImage(leftImage);
    setRightImage(rightImage);
    setClickListener(this);
    //默认显示返回按键
    showBackUpButton(showBackup);
    setToolbarElevation(showElevation);
    setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
}
```

Comment: Set `android:layout_above="@+id/custom_title"` for your `AppBarLayout` or `android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"` for your `custom_title`

Comment: sorry!I want to make the custom_title cover the system title(Toolbar), not below.

Comment: Then customize your tool bar and put your `custom_title` under `ToolBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with `elevation` attributes, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
        ...>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            ...
            android:elevation="0dp">

            ...
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom_title"
            ...
            android:elevation="2dp">

            ...
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can have a try.Overlay the custom layout on the Toolbar, and you'll find that the Toolbar is always at the top, whether you use the FrameLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: @Akid, have you tried changing the elevation like what I'm suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    style="@style/matchwraplayout"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="94dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingTextAppearance.Inverse">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="94dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="name"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mTitle"
                style="@style/toolbartitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/matchwraplayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
   </LinearLayout>
   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I guess, whatever you're trying to do is not feasible with the Toolbar or ActionBar, and secondly you've already created a custom toolbar for your app so I guess you don't really need to include Toolbar in your app at all. You just simply add your custom Toolbar View at the top of your activity/activities and use OnClick listener to handle click events, this will be the better approach.

layout_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="6dp"
tools:parentTag="android.widget.RelativeLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/left_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/left_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Add"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/right_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/right_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="apps.test.test.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" />

    </LinearLayout>
```